# C: string limit? No compiler err/warn- why?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, limit

I am coding some mqtt stuff. The maximum message size for a valid mqtt message is [268435455 bytes approx 260MB](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-broker-message-restrictions/).

Now I encountered several segfaults in my code and it came down I can not use a `*char` of this size in C (Rasbian/ Debian 9: `Linux zentrale 5.10.103-v7+ #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:21:37 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux`).

For testing purposes I wrote the following example program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STRING 268435456 

int main()
{
int i;

void function()
{
        char    message[MAX_STRING];

        printf("0\n");
        memset(message,0,sizeof(message));
        printf("1\n");
        return;
}

i=1;
printf("i: %d\n",i);
i++;
printf("i: %d\n",i);
function();
printf("i: %d\n",i);
}
```

I can compile it without any warnings or errors. When running I am getting the following output:

```
root@rasbpi:/src# ./Beispiel 
i: 1
i: 2
Segmentation fault
```

(original in German: Speicherzugriffsfehler)

I do not understand why I am getting the segfault. If the size is too large shouldn't the compiler complain? If there is no limit and the system is short on memory (which it isn't!) I should get OOM error, but not a segfault.

Anyone able to explain it to me?

Thanks

/KNEBB

Comment: Try to allocate the string in the heap memory using `malloc()`

Comment: Unrelated: Standard C does not allow defining functions inside functions; you are using an extension from your specific compiler and losing portability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating the space for the character array on the stack.

Compilers commonly don't know how much memory is provided for the stack. It would make no sense, since they don't know how much stack the other modules of the final program might use. And if recursion comes into play, the used stack space can be indeterminable.

The linker cannot do it either.

The target's ABI defines the size of the stack.

Common targets have stacks starting at a few dozen bytes (microcontroller) up to some megabytes (PCs).

So you are not hitting a limit of the language, but of your target.

Solve your issue by allocating the needed space with `malloc()`.

Comment: Re “The target's ABI defines the size of the stack”: It is usually the linker. Apple, GNU, and Microsoft linkers have an option to set the stack size.

Comment: Re: “You cannot define a function inside another function”: The fact they do disproves this statement they cannot. The C standard does not define it but allows extensions, and their compiler supports it. So they can, in fact, define a function inside a function.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Is this (the linker sets the stack size) true for all target systems? I don't think so, but my experience is naturally limited. If it is the case, you are technically right, but we can look at this function of the linker as a consequence of the target's requirements. Or so.